# Displaying dropdownlist selected value without the dashes in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display the selected value in my dropdownlist inside a form.
To display the other values (numbers) I'm using `numeral.js` - this work's just fine.

Displaying the selected dropdownlist category will not display the selected options text but rather its value; I would like to display the text inside the option.

Here is what I'm doing.

**ListItem.js**

```
<span>Category: {category}</span>
```

**Form.js**

```
<select value={this.state.category} onChange={this.onCategoryChange}>
    <option value="food-and-drink">Food and Drink</option>
</select>
```

Here is the props that are being sent when form is submitted (for category)

```
category: this.state.category,
```

What the ui looks like

[image: catgeory]

How do I remove the **dashes (-)** between food and drink

Updated with answers from questions (new code):
*State is not changing inside from now when I select option/value from dropdownlist but answer is working, just not for UX*

```
onCategoryChange = (e) => {
    const { selectedIndex } = e.target;
    const text = e.target.options[selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    this.setState({ category: text })
    // const category = e.target.value;
    // this.setState(() => ({ category }));
};

<select value={this.state.category} onChange={this.onCategoryChange}>
    <option value="travel">Travel</option>
    <option value="meeting">Meeting</option>
    <option value="food-and-drink">Food and Drink</option>
</select>
```

**props.onSubmit (form.js)**

```
 this.props.onSubmit({
            category: this.state.category
        });
```

Comment: Can you post all your code? You're doing the wrong thing in your `this.onCategoryChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post your `onCategoryChange()` but it's likely you're passing the `value` of the `<option>` rather than the `text` of the option.

In your case, the `value` is like `'this-is-a-thing'`, and the `text` is like `this is a thing`, so you want to use the `text` not the `value`.

So, you want:

```
onCategoryChange = e => {
  const { selectedIndex } = e.target;
  const text = e.target.options[selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  console.log(text) // gives you 'Food and Drink'
  this.setState({ category: text })
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and here is my onCategoryChange() code: `// Category
    onCategoryChange = (e) => {
        const category = e.target.value;
        this.setState(() => ({ category }));
    };`

Comment: so .text after my e.target.value?

Comment: Thanks, both answers work - the only thing now. When I select food and drink from the dropdownlist - the state doesn't change and it stays at the default value which for me is 'Travel'. Any indication on what is causing this not to change?

Comment: Can you **please** just update your question so I can see your code?

Comment: All good Colin - Riwu mentioned it in his answer - many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to store the option's text in the state for form submission:

```
onCategoryChange = e => this.setState({ 
  category: e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text 
})
```

You don't need `value={this.state.category}` on the `<select />` component unless you need it to be a controlled component (eg. set initial option  from a persisted value). If so, you can use another state to store the value, or create an object and use it for the mapping from value to text.

Comment: I've just updated my question; your answer also works just fine but I have the same problem when I click on an option from the dropdownlist.

Comment: I already mentioned that above. Either remove the `value` prop on your `<select />`, or use another state to store the value and update it in `onCategoryChange` from `e.target.value`, then set the `value` prop to that state.

Comment: Just tried and it is now working perfect! Thank you! Sorry I didn't recognise this extra piece of information.